# finding the AR camera in the latest version of unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

when I'm using the 2017.1   version then I can add the AR(Augmented reality) camera by importing the vafuria the go-to gameobject>>UI>>AR  manual.

NOW using the latest version Unity 2019.2  how can we add the vafuria and also the AR(augmented reality ) camera. By which it will show the option of the AR.

Answer (score 0):

Vuforia works like an internal plugin package these days. Go "project setting>Player", go down, "XR Setting>Vuforia augmented reality support", toggle on. and it should start importing things. After that you can find AR camera in menu "GaemObject/Vuforia Engine/AR Camera"